# writing first react native tests and getting Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

Just started writing the first test case into a existing code base and getting this error.

```
    /XXX/node_modules/@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/index.js:3
    import listenToKeyboardEvents from './lib/KeyboardAwareHOC'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       9 |   StyleSheet,
      10 | } from 'react-native';
    > 11 | import {Body, Button, Header, Icon, Left, Right, Title} from 'native-base';
```

native-base: v2.15

React native info:

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Linux 6.0 Arch Linux
    CPU: (12) x64 AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
    Memory: 46.39 GB / 62.70 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.20.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 33
      Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.1, 33.0.2, 34.0.0
      System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.64.4 => 0.64.4 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

The simple test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Welcome from './Welcome';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should render without errors', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Welcome />);
    expect(container.firstChild).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should match snapshot', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Welcome />);
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Was writing a test case with snapshot testing.
Please suggest how to fix this. Thanks.